# React Native: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined - Have NavigatorIOS and ES6 bind(this)

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, facebook, react-native

I am developing a react native application and I am attempting to route the user to the next view after successfully logging in through Facebook.

The problem is that I continue to get an error stating "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined." I have checked all the related answers on the forum and I have made sure to include NavigatorIOS and bind(this) on my function call - so those are the issue.

I would love assistance in determining what is wrong, as I am a novice dev.

## Here is the error:

```
Error: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
 stack: 
  <unknown>                                              index.ios.bundle:1498
  MessageQueue.__invokeCallback                          index.ios.bundle:7235
  <unknown>                                              index.ios.bundle:7151
  guard                                                  index.ios.bundle:7104
  <unknown>                                              index.ios.bundle:7151
  <unknown>                                              index.ios.bundle:7148
  ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.Mixin.perform  index.ios.bundle:6552
  Object.ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.batchedUpdates     index.ios.bundle:15885
  Object.batchedUpdates                                  index.ios.bundle:5084
 URL: undefined
 line: undefined
 message: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

============================

## Here is my code

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var Main = require('./App/Components/Main');
var Icon = require('./node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome');
var FacebookLoginManager = require('NativeModules').FacebookLoginManager;
var {
AppRegistry,
StyleSheet,
Text,
View,
TouchableHighlight,
NavigatorIOS,
Navigator,
} = React;

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
 welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
 instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
    marginTop: 10
 },
 icon: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: 'white',
    paddingVertical: 5,
    paddingHorizontal: 8,
    borderRadius: 4,
    backgroundColor: '#3b5998',
 },
text: {
    marginLeft: 10,
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: '600',
},
});

class nomsyapp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      result: 'Find the Foods that Fit Your Lifestyle',
      loggedIn: false,
    };
  }

  login() {
    FacebookLoginManager.newSession((error, info) => {
      if (error) {
        this.setState({result: error});
      } else {
        this.setState({result: info});
        this.setState({loggedIn: true});
        this.props.navigator.push({
          component: Main,
          title: 'Choose Your Lifestyle',
        });
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.login.bind(this)}>
         <Icon name="facebook" style={styles.icon}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Login with Facebook</Text>
          </Icon>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          {this.state.result}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
};


AppRegistry.registerComponent('nomsyapp', () => nomsyapp);
```

============================

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the format you need for your initial route:

```
render: function() {
  return (
    <NavigatorIOS
      initialRoute={{
        component: nomsyapp,
        title: 'Nomsyapp',
        passProps: { /*whatever props you want */ },
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

This example is based off of the [Facebook docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigatorios.html).

Thus, you should move all of your current code into another component and create a new component with the render function displayed above. Then the `nomsyapp` component will have the `navigator` property and you'll be able to navigate routes.

Comment: So I changed my index.ios.js file to reflect what you said and them made my current code a view called Login.js -> but now it just initally routes to a blank page with the title passed in the initial route..